# stopping/killing a process using command prompt without knowing the PID

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am starting a notepad from command prompt using the command:

`start notepad`

I am not aware of the `PID` of this instance of notepad. In such a case, how can I close the same instance of notepad using some other commands in command prompt?

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [TASKKILL - End one or more processes (by process id or image name).](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

**Syntax**

TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
         { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/F] [/T]

...

> Filters    Apply one of the Filters below:
>
> - Imagename   eq, ne                  String
> - PID         eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Positive integer.
> - Session     eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Any valid session number.
> - Status      eq, ne                  RUNNING | NOT RESPONDING
> - CPUTime     eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Time hh:mm:ss
> - MemUsage    eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le  Any valid integer.
> - Username    eq, ne                  User name ([Domain]User).
> - Services    eq, ne                  String The service name
> - **Windowtitle eq, ne                  String**
> - Modules     eq, ne                  String The DLL name

You need to use a command like the following:

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq NotepadWindowTitle"
```

Comment: This did not work for me....:-(

Answer (score 1):

> taskkill /im notepad.exe /f

more about taskkill [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx).

If you have more than one notepad.exe open, you can use [tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) to get the PID.

Comment: This is fine. But in some cases, when I run a couple of Java Based desktop application, both the names comes as `java.exe`. In such a scenario, if I need to close one of them then how can I understand which java.exe represents which java application? please suggest

Comment: ya thats fine but how will I understand which notepad is the first instance and which one is the second?

Comment: taskkill can use window title, assuming the window has a title.

Comment: The window I have does have a title and this is something I was looking for. Please let me know how will the command `taskkill` be used for closing a window with title: `demo` ?